# How to Run Systemd Service file with root access in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mongodb, root, ubuntu-16.04, systemd, systemctl

I am having a service file for mongodb at   /lib/systemd/system/mongod.service

and my file contains following data as below

```
[Unit]
Description=High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
After=network.target
Documentation=https://docs.mongodb.org/manual

[Service]
User=mongodb
Group=mongodb
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --quiet --fork --config /etc/mongod.conf
# file size
LimitFSIZE=infinity
# cpu time
LimitCPU=infinity
# virtual memory size
LimitAS=infinity
# open files
LimitNOFILE=64000
# processes/threads
LimitNPROC=64000
# total threads (user+kernel)
TasksMax=infinity
TasksAccounting=false

# Recommended limits for for mongod as specified in
# http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/ulimit/#recommended-settings

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

So while Running the Command as below

```
sudo /usr/bin/mongod --quiet --fork --config /etc/mongod.conf
```

my command running successfully but coming to Service File it is getting Error due to No Root Access.

So i want to run my systemd service file as root access.Any Suggestion would be appreciated and thanks in advance

Comment: This really should be asked on [dba,stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com) which is for questions and answers relating to database administration and configuration. StackOverflow is for :"programming" based questions, of which this is not. Please move your post to the appropriate site instead of posting here.

Comment: I am not asking about database @Neil Lunn , i am asking question about systemd service file and how to run it with root access  and Thanks for replying my post

Comment: Which is **not** a programming question. So you are posting on the wrong site. Understand now?

Comment: What is the error and what is the command you are using to run mongo as a systemd service? And, to nitpick, these files are called Unit files, as in systemd units. I am not sure service file is the right term.

Comment: i am using   `sudo systemctl start mongod.service` for starting  and  `sudo systemctl status mongod.service`

Comment: I have Solved my issue by using 'sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongod' and 'sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/log/mongodb'
`

Comment: Ok will ask to stackexchange next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the Issue to Run the Service as daemon , i have to give full privileges to Mongodb database and Log path for User=mongodb & Group=mongodb by running below commands

```
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb

sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/log/mongodb
```

Answer (score 0):

The `mongodb.service` files normally includes:

```
User=mongodb
Group=mongodb
```

So your problem is elsewhere. You should post the exact error you describing as "Error due to No Root Access" and the command you run that generates it.

In the future, a better site for `systemd` related questions is http://unix.stackexchange.com